# Java, работа с Socket. Socket#isConnected не изменяется при отключении клиента!

Tags: java, многопоточность, сервер, сокет, вложенные-классы

Есть класс для создания сервера и управления подключениями:

```
public abstract class Server {

    //...
    public void start() {
        new Thread(() -> {

             while(true) {
                try {
                    Socket connection = server.accept();

                    // новый поток для сокета
                    new Thread(new Monitor(connection)).start();

                } catch (IOException e) {
                    System.out.println("Accept filed!");
                }
            }
        }).start();
    }

    private class Monitor implements Runnable {
        Socket socket;
        DataInputStream input;
        StringBuilder message;
        boolean status = true;

        public Monitor(Socket socket) {
            this.socket = socket;
            try {
                input = new DataInputStream(socket.getInputStream());
            } catch (IOException e) {
                status = false;
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void run() {
            while (status) {

                try {
                    // если disconnected
                    if(!socket.isConnected()) break;

                    // если есть новые данные 
                    if (input.available() > 0) {

                        message = new StringBuilder();
                        do {
                            message.append(input.readChar());
                        } while(input.available() > 0);

                        onMessage(socket, message.toString());
                    }

                    Thread.sleep(1000);
                }
                catch(IOException | InterruptedException e) {
                    break;
                }
            }

            onDisconnect(socket);
            connections.remove(socket);
        }
    }
}
```

Проблема в том, что при отключении клиента `socket.isConnected()` продолжает остаться `true` и никакой `exception` не появляется.
В чем причина??

Answer (score 0):

`available()` действительно не бросает ошибок.

Есть 2 способа понять что с сокетом проблемы:

1. Поймать `IOException` при чтении
2. Установить таймаут у сокета и поймать `SocketTimeoutException`

Для изменения вашего кода нужно разобраться что мы хотим сделать. Вы ожидаете от клиента некоторое сообщение(пакет), но при этом вы не знаете его размер.  Вам нужно определиться сколько символов(байт и т.д.) нужно прочитать или что будет служить признаком конца сообщения, для того что бы начать обрабатывать сообщение. В вашем случае для определения конца сообщения можно использовать символ новой строки `\n`. Например:

```
public void run() {
    message = new StringBuilder();
    char sym;

    while(status) {
        try {
            sym = input.readChar();

            if(sym == '\n') {
                onMessage(socket, message.toString());
                message = new StringBuilder();
            } else {
                message.append(sym);
            }
        } catch (IOException e) {
            status = false;
        }
    }
}
```

И добавить таймаут соединения:

```
this.socket = socket;
socket.setSoTimeout(10_000);
```

Comment: Не помогло и вообще никакие изменения сокета невидны, никак не получается выйти из цикла. Приходилось использовать `OutputStream#read`, но все же не понимаю почему `Socket#isClosed, Socket#isOutputShutdown` и другие никак не изменяются при отключении сокета?